# Filter out blank for a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there was a way to run a macro in VBA to filter out blanks for a specific column. The column currently has either -1 or blanks in the cells. I am trying to add a macro so that it removes the blanks and only leaves the -1's in the cells. Thank you.

[image: I provided a picture of the column that I am trying to filter showing how there are blanks and non blanks.]

This is the code that I am attempting to run this macro.

[image]

Comment: Tell use about the "blanks".  Are the cells genuinely empty or do they have formulas returning "blank"??

Comment: It is genuinely empty. I just need a way to filter out the blanks then I can resume with my macro.

Comment: If you select L2 and press Ctrl+down arrow, does the cursor stop above the first blank cell, or go to the bottom of the column?

Comment: Hey Rory. It stops above the first blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.K.  Here is an example for blanks in column **Z** 
The rows will be hidden rather than deleted.

```
Sub HideSome()
    Dim rHide As Range, col As String
    col = "Z"
    Set rHide = Intersect(Range(col & ":" & col), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

Here is a version the uses the proper tab and the proper column:

```
Sub HideSome()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet
    Set s2 = Sheets("Current")
    Dim rHide As Range, col As String
    col = "Z"
    s2.Activate
    Set rHide = Intersect(Range(col & ":" & col), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    s1.Activate
End Sub
```

We go to the tab with the data.....hide the rows....then return......

Comment: I just ran this code and it highlighted the part

`Set rHide = Intersect(Range(col & ":" & col), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

It is saying "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Are you using column **Z?**  Are there both blanks and non-blanks in the column?  Are using using a **Sub** or a function??

Comment: The column that I am trying to filter out of my worksheet is "L". There are blanks and non blanks in this column. I am trying to filter the blanks out. I am pretty sure I am using a Sub. I used the exact code that you wrote except with a different Sub name.

Comment: Post the code you actually wrote and we will take a look.

Comment: Hey I just posted the code (like I said I just used the code that you gave me so thanks for that) and a picture of the column I am targeting with blanks and non blanks. Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: The problem is that you need to make the **Set rHide** statement one long line rather than two lines!

Comment: it is one line long. it just cuts off at ActiveSheet on stackoverflow and sends it to the next line. I just edited the code to show a picture of what the code looks like on vba

Comment: Also make sure the sheet you posted is the activesheet when the macro is run.

Comment: The sheet is not the active sheet when the macro is run because I included buttons on another page for anyone else who uses the macro. I would be on the other page when I run the macro. Should I just move the button to the active sheet?

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet containing the data to be filtered??

Comment: That sheet is Sheet2 or "Current"

Comment: Thank you so much Gary's Student. This is the second time you have helped me solve a problem. Wish I could buy you a beer. Here's a best answer and an upvote anyways.